# How to update nested object property in Redux + React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

So first, the `user` object with a few properties (`name`, `color`, `age`) gets set up via `SET_USER`, and I would like to update the `name` property inside the `user` object via `UPDATE_USER_NAME`, yet when I do it with the following code down below with the nested looped in `UPDATE_USER_NAME`, the `name` property doesn't get updated.

What am I doing wrong? If I do something like `user: {action.name, ...state.user}`, the object `user` gets updated and works, but that just creates another new property from `action.name` rather than updating the current `name` inside the `user` object.

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  user: {},
}

export default function(state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {\
  switch(action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
      }

    case actionTypes.UPDATE_USER_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          name: action.name,
          ...state.user,
        }
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: I find a nice way to do "merged" new object creation is to use the [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) api.

Comment: For example... `user: Object.assign({}, state.user, { name: action.name })`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to change the order of the spread a bit:

```
case actionTypes.UPDATE_USER_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          ...state.user,
          name: action.name,
        }
      }
```

This will set `user` to the current `state.user` and then override `name`.  the spread works like `Object.assign` (from left to right).  This is because assigning the same keys in an object literal will be "last one wins".